# Outlook 2007 client rule to MOVE (not copy) a mail after sending to a specific folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, rules

I'm using Microsoft Outlook 2007 and I want to create a rule that moves each sent e-mail to the folder "inbox" so that I have a view of all incoming and sent mails together and can file them where they belong.

My problem is: 
when configuring rules in Outlook, there is no option to MOVE a mail (only copy), so that I end up with 2 copies of the mail.

Is there a trick to get a "move" action in the Outlook rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second copy is in the Sent items folder then

File | Options | Mail
Save Messages
Uncheck "Save copies of messages in Sent items folder"

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  I have multiple email accounts but any received messages, regardless of which account they are addressed to are copied into all the other Inboxes as well.

Apparently IMAP doesn't do this, but you can't delete messages on IMAP, which is why I choose to remain with POP.

With the good old Windows Live Mail, it doesn't have all the fancy Bells & Whistles, but at least it works the way it's meant to.  Less is definitely More.

If it weren't for the fact that I need to be familiar with Outlook for work, I wouldn't bother with it at all.